# How to change Kendo Grid row colours

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, client-side

I want to design my Kendo Grid with colours in each row. If there is an alarm in the database these rows must be red, otherwise they must be green.

Here is my code:

```
public JsonResult Getdata()
{
    var reports = db.ActivityLog.OrderBy(c => c.dateTime).ToList();
    var collection = reports.Select(x => new
    {
        username = x.uName,
        location = x.locName,
        devices = x.devName,
        alarm = x.alarm
    });
    return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My view:

```
function handleDataFromServer() {

    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}

window.setInterval("handleDataFromServer()", 10000);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: false
        },
        selectable: "multiple",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "/Home/Getdata",
                type: "json"
            }
        },
        columns: [
                        { field: "username", width: "80px" },
                        { field: "location", width: "80px" },
                        { field: "devices", width: "80px" },
                        { field: "alarm", width: "80px" }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a RowTemplate, and in that RowTemplate evaluate a css class for the given row based on whatever condition you provide.  The css class could then have the stylings appropriate for that row.  For example, "no-alarm", or "with-alarm" could be placed on 'td' and set a background color.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/rowtemplate.html

**Example**

You can evaluate your data item in the row template and cleanly output the given class.  In this example (available in the jsfiddle link below) a user has a name and age...if the age is <= 30, they get the 'underthirty' class (really it should be thirtyorunder class).

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td class='#= age <= 30 ? "underthirty" : "overthirty"#'>
            <strong>#= name #</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            #= age #
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjacketmack/t7fF2/1/

Comment: How can I determinate row's color? for example if alarm not null, row is green... I think this is not solve my problem

Comment: I added an example...basically, you can evaluate properties of your object in the row template (using an inline 'if' statement for instance) and output the appropriate class.  I like this solution because it is extremely clean, and keeps the styling (css) close to the structure (html).

Comment: Why was this unaccepted...2 years later no less?  Sad to see a little -15 in activity, but to take away an accepted answer and apply it to your own answer feels a little funny.

Answer (score 17):

I solved by adding this function in the kendo grid function.

```
columns: [
                    { field: "username", width: "80px" },
                    { field: "location", width: "80px" },
                    { field: "devices", width: "80px" },
                      { field: "alarm", width: "80px" }],
dataBound: function () {
                dataView = this.dataSource.view();
                for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
                    if (dataView[i].alarmID!=null) {
                        var uid = dataView[i].uid;
                        $("#grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]").addClass("alarm");  //alarm's in my style and we call uid for each row
                    }
                    else if (dataView[i].message!=null) {
                        var uid = dataView[i].uid;
                        $("#grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]").addClass("reason");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nice solution. The positive of it is that I don't have to change my columns[]  setting in de grid definition, and replace it by a rowtemplate.   +1!      you are using a direct reference to $('#grid tbody').  I would replace it by this:   dataBound:function(e){e.sender.element.find("tr..")}   Then you could reuse this function on several grids, and it just looks cleaner imho

Comment: This solution is so much better since you can add columns later and don't have to worry about display. Plus: if you add @JDC solution, the solution becomes entirely reusable in every grid. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: you can use `this.tbody` instead of `$("#grid tbody")` to enable a more generic solution

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the dataBound of kendoGrid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .red {
    background-color: red
  }
    .green {
    background-color: green
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ 
    {
        field: "name",
        title: "Name",
        },
         {
    field: "title",
    title: "Title"
    }
   ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe", title: "Dr. Dr." }, { name: "John Doe", title: "Senior Citizen" }],
  dataBound: function(e) {
                var items = this._data;
                var tableRows = $(this.table).find("tr");
                tableRows.each(function(index) {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var Item = items[index];
                    if (Item.name !== "Jane Doe") {
                        row.addClass("green");
                    }else{
                        row.addClass("red");
                    }
                });
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```